# Removing elements in an array using Lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have this array:

```
var fruits = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'Celery'];
```

And I use Lodash's `remove` like so:

```
_.remove(fruits, function (fruit) {
  return fruit === 'Apple' || 'Banana' || 'Orange';
})
```

The result is `['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'Celery']`, while I expected it to be `['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange']`. Why is this so?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Because when `fruit` is `"Celery"`, you are testing:

```
"Celery" === 'Apple' || 'Banana' || 'Orange'
```

which evaluates to

```
false || true || true
```

which is `true`.

You can't use that syntax. Either do it the long way around:

```
_.remove(fruits, function (fruit) {
  return fruit === 'Apple' || fruit === 'Banana' || fruit === 'Orange'
});
```

or test for array membership:

```
_.remove(fruits, function (fruit) {
  return _.indexOf(['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange'], fruit) !== -1
});
```

This is not limited to JavaScript, and is in fact a common mistake (e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002503/why-does-a-b-or-c-or-d-always-evaluate-to-true))

Comment: Why not use `_.includes` instead of `_.indexOf`?

Answer (score 37):

You can use the method `_.pull` from lodash 2.0 and up

```js
var fruits = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'Celery'];

_.pull(fruits, 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange'); // ['Celery']

document.write(fruits);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.6.1/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 13):

If you want to remove a set of items from another set, there are set operations intended specifically for that.  Lodash has https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#difference which takes two array parameters A and B and will return another array which contains all of the elements of A which are not in B.

In your case, you could write

```
const fruits = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'Celery'];
const filteredFruits = _.difference(fruits, ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange']);
```

which will result in `['Celery']`.

Answer (score 10):

The problem isn't with Lo-Dash; your problem is with your conditional within your callback function. This:

```
return fruit === 'Apple' || 'Banana' || 'Orange';
```

Is **not** correct. You need to actually compare `fruit` with each string:

```
return fruit === 'Apple' || fruit === 'Banana' || fruit === 'Orange';
```

*Or*, you can use another Lo-Dash function to make it a little more compact:

```
_.remove(fruits, function (fruit) {
  return _.contains(['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange'], fruit);
})
```

**Note:** In the latest versions of Lo-Dash the `_.contains` function is deprecated. Please use [`_.includes`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#includes)

Answer (score 2):

Use an array of values that you'd like to compare against, and check for a returned index greater than -1. This indicates the value evaluated was found in the collection.

```
_.remove( fruits, function ( fruit ) {
  return _.indexOf( [ "Apple", "Banana", "Orange" ], fruit ) >= 0;
});
```

Alternatively you could use [lo-dash's `_.contains` method](https://lodash.com/docs#contains) to get a boolean response.

The problem with the approach you took was that you weren't comparing `fruit` against each one of those strings; instead, the only comparison taking place was `fruit` against `"Apple"`, after that you were coercing strings all on their own.

Non-empty strings coerce to `true` (`!!"Banana"`), and as such are *truthy*. Therefore, the following condition will always short-circuit at "Banana" (unless `fruit` strictly equals `"Apple"`), returning `true`:

```
return fruit === "Apple" || 'Banana' || "Orange";
```

Comment: Note: Lodash no longer uses the function ``_.contains``. It used to be an alias for ``_.includes``, but is no longer as of 3.10.0. Use ``_.includes`` instead. https://github.com/mgonto/restangular/issues/1298