# How to remove object with Lodash (find and remove)

Tags: javascript, lodash

I want remove with **Lodash**, the object with uuid: xxx and not xxx2.

How I can make this with **Lodash** ?

```
[
    {
        "uuid": "xxx",
        "name": "test"
    },
    {
        "uuid": "xxx2",
        "name": "test 2"
    }
]
```

My actual code:

```
_.forEach(this.objs, (obj, index, collection) => {
   _.remove(obj, {uuid})
})
```

Comment: You can use filter `arr = arr.filter(({uuid}) => uuid !== 'xxx');`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing elements in an array using Lodash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28036716/removing-elements-in-an-array-using-lodash)

Comment: There is _.filter to return a new array or _.remove to change it in place.

Comment: Using loadash `_.remove(arr, ({uuid}) => uuid === 'xxx')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simple use [_.remove](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#remove) method.

```js
var objects = [
    {
        "uuid": "xxx",
        "name": "test"
    },
    {
        "uuid": "xxx2",
        "name": "test 2"
    }
];

_.remove(objects, o => o.uuid === 'xxx2');

console.log(objects);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You can also use `_.remove(objects, { uuid: 'xxx2' });`

Comment: @CélineMartin press `Run code snippet` button in my answer. or give me your expected output ?

Comment: @MohamedAbbas This, return me only element removed and not the list without this object... I haven't error.

Comment: @CélineMartin i'm sorry can you write an example for your expected output, you can put it in https://www.jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.filter()` for that

```js
let arr = [
    {
        "uuid": "xxx",
        "name": "test"
    },
    {
        "uuid": "xxx2",
        "name": "test 2"
    }
]


arr = arr.filter(e => e.uuid != 'xxx2');

console.log(arr);
```